# Issue listing regtest wallets

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-cli, regtest, source-code

## Questions:

1. Should it be assumed if you're testing with bitcoincore you should always have a separate datadir per version/bin?
2. Based on weirdness below, (not being able to list regtest wallets), does it seem like my current node is messed up? If yes, what should I do to recover? If no, what am I doing wrong?

## Details:

I was running version v25.0 of bitcoincore from bitcoincore.org. I crated some wallets and did some testing. I then compiled from master/source `bitcoin/bitcoin` and pointed to the same backend state/datadir that v25.0 was using. Later I switched back to running the binary v25.0.

I'm curious if that could be the reason for seeing weird things like this or if it's something else:

```
$ ./bitcoin-cli createwallet wallet_main
error code: -4
error message:
Wallet file verification failed. Failed to create database path '/btcdata/regtest/wallets/wallet_main'. Database already exists.

$ ./bitcoin-cli listwallets
[
]

$ ./bitcoin-cli createwallet wallet_main33
{
  "name": "wallet_main33"
}

$ ./bitcoin-cli listwallets
[
  "wallet_main33"
]

$ ./bitcoin-cli createwallet wallet_main
error code: -4
error message:
Wallet file verification failed. Failed to create database path '/btcdata/regtest/wallets/wallet_main'. Database already exists.
```

I was doing some testing on regtest a few days ago and created several wallets including a "wallet_main", it seems there is still some data of this and other regtest wallets, but they don't show up with the `listwallets` command.

Am I doing something wrong to list the all the wallets? Is it maybe a bug? or did I perhaps mess up my node?

Additional notes:
Inside my `/btcdata/regtest/wallets/` directory all my wallets look the same in term user/permissions the folder for the wallet names are 700, `drwx------`, and the inner `wallet.dat`'s are 600, `-rw-------`. I indeed have a `/btcdata/regtest/wallets/wallet_main` dir.

Comment: When you're using regtest (or testnet or signet) you're supposed to add `-regtest` to the `bitcoin-cli` command, so it can find the right data directory and config file sections. I'm surprised anything works at all without that.

Comment: To actually answer your question: you may need to issue `loadwallet` RPC to load existing wallets, if they're not set to auto loading. If that resolves it, I'll turn this into an answer.

Comment: Yes, brain fart.. `loadwallet` is what I need to do. I also see there is detailed explanation within bitcoin.conf to help people autoload various wallets.

Also,
bitcoin.conf set to run regtest via `chain=regtest` so I don't need to put `-regtest` it in every command. (I believe this is how it works?) 
Also doing this in bitcoin.conf:
```
# Options for regtest
[regtest]
# Options for regtest
[regtest]
rpcport=8332
fallbackfee=0.01
```
You're good to turn your comment into an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `listwallets` RPC only lists *loaded* wallets.

If you want to load an existing wallet, you need the `loadwallet` RPC first.